# In an assignment I was given I am supposed to write a program to output the lyrics to 99 bottles of beer on the wall,

Tags: visual-c++

I can't seem to get it to count down on the last verse. I've tried to create a new variable that subtracts 1 and put that variable in the last verse and it works for all but numbers 9, 19, 29, 39...99. Can someone please give me a hint or point me in the right direction? I've also tried creating another loop to count down and read it from the array. I have only been learning this for a few months and don't know what else to try. I thought I once I got to this point the hard part was behind me, not so much, for me at least. Thank you. It is c++ in Visual studio 2010.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string tens[11] = {""," Ten"," Twenty"," Thirty"," Forty"," Fifty"," Sixty"," Seventy"," Eighty"," Ninety"};
string ones[10] = {"","-One","-Two","-Three","-Four","-Five","-Six","-Seven","-Eight","-Nine"};
string s_ones[11] = {" Zero"," One"," Two"," Three"," Four"," Five"," Six"," Seven"," Eight"," Nine"};
string other[ ] = {" Ten"," Eleven"," Twelve"," Thirteen"," Fourteen"," Fifteen"," Sixteen"," Seventeen"," Eighteen"," Nineteen",""};


int main()
{
    for(int i = 99; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        int tens_place = i / 10, ones_place = i % 10, small_ones_place = i % 10;


        if(10 <= i && i < 20)
        {
            cout << other[i - 10] << " bottles of beer on the wall. \n"
                 << other[i - 10] << " bottles of beer.\n"
                 << " Take one down, pass it around,\n"
                 << other[(i - 10)] << " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n";
        }
        if(20 <= i && i <= 99)

            cout << tens[tens_place] + ones[ones_place] << " bottles of beer on the wall. \n"
                 << tens[tens_place] + ones[ones_place] << " bottles of beer.\n"
                 << " Take one down, pass it around,\n"
                 << tens[tens_place] + ones[ones_place] << " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n";

        if(2 <= i && i < 10)

            cout << s_ones[small_ones_place] << " bottles of beer on the wall.\n"
                 << s_ones[small_ones_place] << " bottles of beer.\n"
                 << " Take one down, pass it around,\n"
                 << s_ones[small_ones_place] << " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n";

        if(i == 1)

            cout << s_ones[small_ones_place] << " bottle of beer on the wall.\n"
                 << s_ones[small_ones_place] << " bottle of beer.\n"
                 << " Take one down, pass it around,\n"
                 << s_ones[small_ones_place] << " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n";

        if(i == 0)

            cout << s_ones[small_ones_place] << " bottles of beer on the wall.\n"
                 << s_ones[small_ones_place] << " bottles of beer.\n"
                 << " Go to the store and get some more,\n"
                 << " Ninety-nine bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n";

        }
return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes very close to working correctly.  All you have to do is subtract 1 from the one's place index on the last line.  Like this:

```
<< " Take one down, pass it around,\n"
<< other[(i - 10)-1] << " bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've tried that, It only works for the numbers in that range, 10 to 20. I can't get it to work for the other numbers. When I created new variables for the int tens_place, ones_place and small_ones_place I subtracted one from there too but It doesn't output 9, 19, 29, 39,....etc correctly. It just leaves a blank or the number above it.

Comment: @user1848538: You just need conditional logic when ones_place == 0.  In that case, your new tens_place is 1 less, and your new ones_place is 9.

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it. It's probably alot longer than it needs to be but it does what it's supposed to do. I ended up combining the s_ones and other array, added twenty to it and then added a conditional logic statement like you suggested and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: yeah, I'm not looking for anyone to just give me the answer. I am trying to learn this but there are so many ways to make a million mistakes. It is frustrating when I'm not sure exactly what I'm being asked to do. I've only been at this about 3 months and there is so much more to learn. Again thank you for your help.